# How do I run a simple C++ program in the Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: c++, cloud9-ide

I am working on a translation application in my high school Computer Science Advanced Studies class. MY school's computers have a CodeBlocks IDE, but no compiler installed. So, I decided to try and find one online that I can use, and Cloud9 seemed like a good prospect. However, when I try to run my program, I get errors such as the following:

```
g++: error: /home/ubuntu/workspace/English-Spanish: No such file or directory            
g++: fatal error: no input files     
compilation terminated.          
chmod: cannot access ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/runme’: No such file ordirectory                                      
sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/workspace/runme: not found
```

I'm not sure where the problem is or how to fix it. Any tips? I'm new to the online IDE scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. It was a simple mistake, really. My project's filename was "English-Spanish Translator," but spaces are not acceptable for filenames. I renamed it "eng-esp_translate.cpp," and it ran just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't add any source code to your project.